# How do you run a project in Ninja-IDE as root?

Tags: python

I have a project in Ninja-IDE that I need to run as root. How can I do that from the IDE?  I tried to run the project after running Ninja-IDE as root but that did not work.  I still get 'permission denied' when running my project.

Comment: Why do you have to run it from the IDE?

Comment: Because I want to be able to just hit F6 and run it.

Comment: Why is this question getting down votes?  What am I missing?  It seems like a pretty simple question and I have not been able to find an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask maybe? In doing my due diligence before asking questions, I often answer them myself (or come quite close to it). There's a sense that you're asking people to figure out where/how a specific IDE performs a specific task without having done any work yourself. Also, it's not really a coding question, which is something that's sort of frowned on here.

Comment: It is a question specific to an IDE and the documentation for said IDE is worthless in this regard.  I'll just delete the question and forget about.  I know I can run my program from the console, but would prefer to do it within the IDE...

Answer (score 1):

Here: I found the source code for this project, searched for "F6", searched for the resulting term "execute-project", searched for the resulting term, "execute_project", followed the code a bit, found the eventual call to a sort of generic "call executable" helper. It in turn leads to a 'run widget', which handles the pre-execute, execute, and post-execute for project execution.

[Here's the link to that portion of the code.](https://github.com/ninja-ide/ninja-ide/blob/b4e057617f032eda40438738a55ed1adcbbc8158/ninja_ide/gui/tools_dock/run_widget.py#L208)

All this is to say that it might be as simple as changing settings.PYTHON_EXEC to "sudo python". Depending on your OS, this might break, since `sudo` will likely be looking for a password. It's a good start though, I think ;)

For sudo and password prompt issues, try [this thread on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470383/how-to-avoid-prompt-password-for-sudo).

Comment: Thank you!  I am using Raspbian so I think just adding sudo will work for me.  I'm new to *nix, python, rasberry pi, etc.